# Can I adjust my blinds for both ventilation and privacy?

Tags: ventilation, blinds

I like fresh air so I usually open the window a little and keep the blinds to the angle that I think nobody can see me from outside.

Today I feel very upset because I found out everybody can see me from the outside. I didn't know this about for two years.

Questions:

1. Is there any alternative solution that could satisfy my need for both ventilation and privacy?
2. Will it help if I replace the blinds in that window with big wood blinds?

I live in the U.S.

Comment: What angle do you usually use?

Comment: Whether neighbors are offended probably varies by locality. You might inquire with a nearby acquaintance you've recently met. In some cities, I've seen apartments where people make no effort at all to screen their windows, night or day, and do all manner of activities in full sight. In some cities, the rule is if you don't like what you see, don't look! In other areas, you could be accused of "putting on a show" if you don't make at least some attempt at screening your windows. Welcome to the US.

Comment: Since legality questions are OT per our [faq], I've removed that part. Legality will be location specific (your state and possibly county), and may depend on your intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your room is upstairs, have your blinds tilted upwards; the opposite if downstairs.  At night, turn on your lights and slant your blind the way you like and go outside and see how little you can see (if at all).  Having bigger blinds will make it so there are fewer gaps but still the angle is the main issue.

I doubt if the neighbors really pay too much attention unless they are very nosy.  If you are doing your best to close the blinds and they still are annoyed, that is their problem.

As far as legality, you are closing your blinds and what you do behind closed doors is your business.

All the best.

Comment: Why do you need to go outside at all?  It seems to me that if you put your head at the levels you are concerned about, in various parts of the room, and look outside, then if you can see the areas where neighbors would be, then they can see you.